# how to malloc an int * in C

Tags: c, malloc

I want to make a fucntion that load a map in a char ** and return it.
To do this I need to make a function that return an int * with inside it, the length of each line in a char ** give as arguments.
my problem is, it keep segfault and I don't know how to fix this.
when I use valgrind the errors are :
Use of uninitialised value of size 8   ,
Invalid write of size 1

```
int *nb_cols_pline(char *filepath)             //length of each line in char **
{
    int x, y = 0;
    struct stat *size = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    stat(filepath, size);

    int *count = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_lines(filepath));  //first errors may be here

    int fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY);
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size->st_size);
    read(fd, buffer, size->st_size);

    for (y = 0; y < nb_lines(filepath); y++) {
        for (x = 0; buffer[x] != '\n'; x++) {
        }
        count[y] = x;           //maybe second error 
    }
    close(fd);
    free(size); free(buffer);
    return count;
}

char **load_map(char *filepath)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct stat *size = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    stat(filepath, size);

    int *nb_cols = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_lines(filepath));
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size->st_size);

    for (int x = 0; x < nb_lines(filepath); x++) {
        nb_cols[x] = nb_cols_pline(filepath)[x];
    }

    char **map = malloc(sizeof(char *) * nb_lines(filepath) + 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < nb_lines(filepath); x++) {
        map = malloc(sizeof(char) * nb_cols[x]);
    }

    int fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buffer, size->st_size);
    for (int y = 0; y < nb_lines(filepath); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < nb_cols[i]; x++) {
            map[y][x] = buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    close(fd);
    free(buffer); free(nb_cols); free(size);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to allocate your struct stat.  Instead of `struct stat *size = malloc(sizeof(struct stat)); stat(filepath, size);`, you should do `struct stat size; stat(filepath, &size);`

Comment: Comment on efficiency: I think you're calling nb_cols_pline for EACH iteration in `nb_cols[x] = nb_cols_pline(filepath)[x];`.  Instead, call it once, and used the returned pointer instead. `int *cols = nb_cols_pline(filepath); for (x = ....) { nb_cols[x] = cols[x]; }`. Also, don't call `nb_lines(filepath)` everywhere if it isn't expected to change. Especially not as part of a loop condition.